# Find the sum of the coefficients of $x^{20}$ and $x^{21}$ in the power series expansion of $\frac 1{(1-x^3)^4}$.

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I know we can factor the bottom using difference of cubes to get $\frac{1}{(1-x)^4(1+2x^3+x^6)^4}$. Then we can take out the $(1-x)^4$ to get $\frac{1}{(1+2x^3+x^6)^4} \cdot [\binom 33 + \binom {4}{3}x + \binom 53x^2 \cdots]$. I don't know how to simplify any further - please tell me if I did something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since
$(1-x)^{-n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{n-1}x^k
$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem),
$(1-x^m)^{-n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{n-1}x^{km}
$.

Therefore
$(1-x^3)^{-4}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+3}{3}x^{3k}
$.

Since there is no term
with $x^{20}$
and the term with
$x^{21}$ corresponds to
$k = 7$,
the result is
$\binom{10}{3}
=120
$.

Answer (score -1):

The power series expansion of $\frac 1{1-y}$ is $1+y+y^2+y^3+\cdots$, which we can think of as the generating function for all nonnegative integers. Substituting $x^3$ for $y$, we get
$$\frac 1{1-x^3} = 1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9 + \cdots$$
and thus
$$\frac 1{(1-x^3)^4} = (1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9 + \cdots)^4.$$
The coefficient of $x^k$ counts the number of ways to write $k$ as the sum of an ordered quadruple of nonnegative multiples of $3$. If $k$ is not itself a multiple of $3$, then there are no such quadruples; thus the coefficient of $x^{20}$ is $0$.

For the coefficient of $x^{21}$, we note that solving
$$a+b+c+d=21$$
with $a,b,c,d$ all multiples of $3$ is equivalent via a substitution to solving
$$a'+b'+c'+d'=7$$
in nonnegative integers. From our work on distribution problems, we know that there are $\binom{7+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{10}3=120$ ways to do this.

Therefore, the sum of the coefficients of $x^{20}$ and $x^{21}$ in the expansion of $\frac 1{(1-x^3)^4}$ is $0+120=\boxed{120}$.

*Solution from AoPS*